# Invariant Factors of a complete tripartite graph

Tags: matrices, spectral-graph-theory

Let $K_{4,4,12}$ be a complete tripartite graph on 20 vertices. Considering its adjacency matrix with a convenient labeling,its nonzero eigenvalues are -4,-8,12. Now the invariant factors are 4,4,24. How did they find the invariant factors in detail, please?

Comment: Who are "they"? (That is, can you give your source?) I find 1,1,2 for the invariant factors, so clearly I am doing a different computation than "they" are.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it is in a  recent published article by Bapat and Karimi under the name of integral complete multipartite graph

Comment: That's probably something you should lead with :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The version of the paper I found](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379518301368) says that the invariant factors are $4,4,24$; we get $1,9,36$ for the second example $K_{2,9,9}$.

In any case, here is how you get there. These are not the invariant factors of the adjacency matrix (there's a result about those elsewhere in the paper) but of the quotient matrix, which in the case of $K_{4,4,12}$ is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 4 & 12 \\ 4 & 0 & 12 \\ 4 & 4 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$
(In general, it has zeroes along the diagonal and otherwise the $(i,j)$ entry is the size of the $j^{\text{th}}$ part of the complete multipartite graph.)

To find the invariant factors, we reduce the matrix to a diagonal matrix in which each diagonal entry divides the next, by doing integer-invertible row and column operations, like so:

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 4 & 12 \\ 4 & 0 & 12 \\ 4 & 4 & 0\end{bmatrix} & \leadsto \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 & 12 \\ 0 & 4 & 12 \\ 4 & 4 & 0\end{bmatrix} & \text{(swap a pivot into $(1,1)$)} \\
& \leadsto \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 & 12 \\ 0 & 4 & 12 \\ 0 & 4 & -12\end{bmatrix} & \text{(subtract row 1 from row 3)} \\
& \leadsto \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 12 \\ 0 & 4 & -12\end{bmatrix} & \text{(subtract $3\times$ column 1 from column 3)} \\
& \leadsto \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 12 \\ 0 & 0 & -24\end{bmatrix} & \text{(subtract row 2 from row 3)} \\
& \leadsto \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -24\end{bmatrix} & \text{(subtract $3\times$ column 2 from column 3)} \\
& \leadsto \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 24\end{bmatrix} & \text{(multiply the third row by $-1$)} \\\end{align}

In general, see [the algorithm on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form#Algorithm).

Comment: I tried doing different elementary row operations but  got 8,8,24. could there be different invariant factors?

Comment: No, the factors are *invariant*. Keep in mind that multiplying a row by a constant is not allowed.

Comment: got it, thank you so much!

Comment: since you have the article, can i please ask one more question?

Comment: In section 2, it says $A$$H$=$H$$Q_{G}$,the definition of $H$ is ambiguous to me. I mean $P_{i}$ is an an independent set of $ p_{i}$ elements hence its adjacency matrix would be the zero matrix. Now they then say that the$ j-th$ column of  $H$ is the characteristic vector of $P_{j}$ i.e. the zero  matrix, also as if there is just one characteristic vector. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: $P_j$ is not a matrix; $P_j$ is a set of vertices. The characteristic vector of $P_j$ is an $n$-dimensional vector (where $n$ is the number of vertices) whose $i^{\text{th}}$ entry is $1$ if the $i^{\text{th}}$ vertex is an element of $P_j$, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: (Indeed, I'm not sure what a characteristic vector of a *matrix* would even be; typically, you can have a characteristic vector only of a subset of some set. You might be thinking of eigenvectors, or of characteristic polynomials?)

Comment: Yes,I was thinking about eigenvectors. Thank you. Also, I just tried seeing that $A$$H$=$H$$Q_{G}$ on an example of a complete bipartite graph, it worked. But can't really see it in general on $K_{p_1,...,p_r}$